# How to fetch and track remote branch from different git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have following scenario with git

master (production) -> branch-dev (modified code) => Repo 1

master (staging, based on production master) -> stage-branch-dev (new branch) => Repo 2

I created a branch from a base app and made some changes to that branch (branch-dev => Repo 1). Then, I created a new repo for a staging environment. Now I want to create new branch `stage-branch-dev` in staging repo (Repo 2) and get all the code from `branch-dev` of Repo 1 so that I can merge that code to staging master first and test the app. Somebody, please guide me on how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are they separate repositories? Wouldn't separate branches in the same repo be much simpler?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have deployed my app on Heroku. I wanted to create a staging environment for my app so I forked it and created a new repository. I don't know If I can have staging environment based on a branch so any suggestions on how I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code from `branch-dev` to `stage-branch-dev` by cherry pick commit:

```
# In Repo2
git checkout stage-branch-dev
git remote add repo1 /path/for/Repo1 -f
gitk --all #find the latest commit id for repo1/branch-dev
git cherry-pick <the commit you found>
# If there has conflict during cherry-pick
# modify and save the conflict files
git add .
git cherry-pick --continue
```